# Questions about Time Logic

Tags: javascript

I have some code that is shown below:

```
var output ="Registration Site, is open";    
if (new Date().getTime() > new Date("2015-07-15 13:13:00").getTime())
                    {
                        output ="Registration Site, is now closed";
                    }
```

So I have a couple questions. The date and time that are currently taken into account are the client side date and time.. So let us say I am CST. So if I am CST then the output will say "Registration Site, is now closed", if the time is 13:13:00... But.. If there was someone in a timezone such as PST. They are 2 hours behind CST. So for them it will be 11:13:00.. So the people in the PST timezone will still be seeing "Registration Site, is open".

Is there a way for us to change this code that it will say "Registration Site, is now closed" for PST users at 13:13:00 their time? And at 13:13:00 PST it will close the registration for everyone, worldwide.

Comment: You might want to check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) which have timezone support.

Comment: Oh thanks Terry. I didn't see that there was a question about it already.